# Relationship among UML classes

Tags: oop, uml, computer-science, software-design

I have to make a **Class Diagram** of an e-mail. After the abstraction, I was able to create 2 classes: **Sender** and **Recipient**. At first I thought the relation between them would be an **aggregation by composition**, since there's not an e-mail without one of those 2 classes.
At the same time, when these 2 classes communicate with each other, another one comes up: **E-mail**. This class is the link/connection of those 2 first ones and, by realizing that, the association is in fact a **ternary association**. Am I right or I'm missing something?
[image: Class Diagram of an e-mail]

Comment: Ternary associations are more intellectual masturbation than a useful construct for modelling in the real world. I would model that as simply two associations from `Email` to `Contact`, one with name `Recipient`, the other with name `Sender`.

Comment: what the classes Sender and Recipient represent ? what difference between the operations having the same name in these classes and Email ?

Comment: @GeertBellekens is right. I never got what for I should use a ternary. Do as he suggested.

Comment: What is the purpose of your class diagram? Is it a domain model (i.e. model of the real world) or a source code model (i.e. model of the source code of an email application) or a database model?

Comment: @Blyatmobile, are you satisfied with one of the answers? Then please mark that answer with a checkmark. If not, why not?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl it's a domain model I think, it's purely an abstraction exercise. I have to create an abstraction of a e-mail (it wasn't specified the service provider) and make the diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In short

Yes, a ternary association is a possibility.  But think of it twice, because many people have difficulties reading ternary associations with hight multiplicity on one branch only.

### More details

There are plenty of ways to model the relationship between an email, a sender, and multiple receivers.  There is no single good answer.  For example:

- `Email` class with associations with `Receiver` and `Sender`
- `Email` class with an aggregation with Reveiver and Sender if you see those as a part of an Email which can be shared (between several emails referring to the same senders or receivers).
- `Email` class with a composition with `Reveiver` and `Sender` if you'd see each sender or receiver as an embedded value object within the emails (so two emails with the same sender address would each have its own copy of the object).
- A `Sender` and a `Receiver` class, with `Email` being an association class
- A ternary association as you have modelled it,
- Not to speak of the case were you would have `Sender` and `Receivers` beign composed with or inheriting from a common denominator `EmailAccount`.

The question is how you want to see all these elements, i.e. your understanding of the world.  For example:

- who `send()` the `Email`:  is it the `Sender` or is it the `Email` or is it the mailbox?  It's not clear in your model where this responsibility lies.
- can an `Email` exist without a `Sender` or a `Receiver`?  I often start to write an email and add the receivers later on (to avoid sending it by accident).  If the answer is yes,  you elminiate the association class.
- is `Receiver` really part of your system? If no, why is there a `read()` opeartion? If yes,  what's the benefit of having a single system email system ?
- how easy do you think the concept of ternary association is to grasp for your readers, whent tehre is a higher multiplicity on one end?

And this leads to the question of what your system really do with emails.  It would be a pitty to model complex relationships with `Senders` and `Receivers` if  in the end those are not needed, because you have just to develop an [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) that needs to get the `Receivers` from an email and make some queries to forward the email to the correct IP addresses.

Maybe a good start for your modeling could therefore be [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#page-16) which explains that senders and receivers are in fact only email addresses,  which would lead to a simplified model with an `Email` class, and `Address` class,  and two associations (one with end `to` and the other with end `from`) between the same classes.

Comment: In the third bullet, do you mean 'composition' instead of 'aggregation'? Because aggregation was already mentioned in the second bullet.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Indeed! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the late reply. Basically it's a question from my homework and it got me confused because all it tells me is to create an abstraction of an e-mail, create a use case diagram and a class one. Nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of your class diagram? Is it a domain model (i.e. model of the real world) or a source code model (i.e. model of the source code of an email application) or a database model?

If the only clue to what you have to do is "Create a class diagram for e-mails', then one class `E-mail` is enough. You already have attributes `Recipient` and `Sender` in your E-mail class, so you can leave out classes `Recipient` and `Sender`.

Comment: My question is basically that, unfortunately, that's why I'm slightly confused. Don't I have to create classes when I'm abstracting something? That's why I created both `Sender` and `Recipient`.

Comment: If you don't have a context in which you can determine whether a class is useful or not, you can model as many classes as you wish: class Person, class Internet, class Server, class TextEditor, class Attachment etc.